# Django: If form doesn't have information set value to

Tags: django, request

If value in interval is not selected, i would like to use default one ( 1d )

```
    # if  i got post request
    if request.method == "POST":
        #  check if interval is choosen in form 
        if 'interval' in request.POST:
            interval= request.POST["interval"]
        else:
            interval = "1d"
        if "ticker" in request.POST:
            ticker= request.POST["ticker"]
```

[image]

the value of intervals is not check properly if is there
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set this default value in frontend. In your html:

```html
<option selected="selected">
1d
</option>
```

I would argue that it is the better option.

You can of course check for empty string in the interval keyword

```py
if request.POST["interval"] == "":
    interval = "1d"
```

Comment: Thank you -  Although I make it otherwise, as It could be also done by adding value parameter this will not change the description
<option selected value='1d'>
select values
</option>